# unable to upload files in nodeJS: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Background:** As part of learning NodeJS, I am creating a web app which allows users to upload pictures on the website. Users select a picture, and once the submit button is clicked, the file is stored in the local directory via `os.tmpDir`, using the formidable module. The file name is also saved on mongoLabs. The idea is that ultimately, all the pictures will be stored on the Amazon S3 bucket, and mongoose will hold the name of each picture uploaded, as well as upvotes/downvotes associated with the picture.

**Problem:** when I click the submit button, the console spits out the following message:

```
fs.js:60
      throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'tempfile' -> 'newfilefunction () {

                gm(newfile).resize(300).write(newfile, function() {



                    fs.readfile(newfile, function(err, buf) { 
                        var req = knoxClient.put(filename, {
                            'Content-Length': buf.length, 
                            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'

                        })

                        req.on('response', function(res) {
                            if (res.statusCode == 200) {

                                var newImage = new singleImageModel({
                                    filename: filename,
                                    votes: 0    
                                }).save();

                                Socket.emit('status', {'message': 'saved!!', 'delay': 3000});
                                socket.emit('doUpdate', {});

                                //recieve these events in index.html

                                fs.unlink(newfile, function() {

                                    console.log('local file deleted');
                                })
                            }
                        })

                        req.end(buf); 
                    })


                });

            }'
    at Error (native)
user-MacBook-Pro:48-project user$
```

When I look at my mongoose database on mongolab, no entry has been made. I know the file is not being uploaded, but I have no idea where I am going wrong. I have provided the full code below :

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config/config.js');
var knox = require('knox'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var gm = require('gm');
var mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.dbURL);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html'); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('host', config.host);

var knoxClient = knox.createClient({
    key: config.S3AccessKey,
    secret: config.S3Secret,
    bucket: config.S3Bucket     
})

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

require('./routes/routes.js')(express, app, formidable, fs, os, gm, knoxClient, mongoose, io);


server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('FromMyLens running on port: ' + app.get('port'));
})
```

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(express, app, formidable, fs, os, gm, knoxClient, mongoose, io) {

    var Socket;
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        Socket = socket;
        console.log("got the socket in routes.js");
    })

    var singleImage = new mongoose.Schema({
        filename: String,
        votes: Number   
    })

    var singleImageModel = mongoose.model('singleImage', singleImage);  
    var router = express.Router();  
    router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
        res.render('index', {host: app.get('host')});   
    })

    router.post('/upload', function(req,res,next) { 
        function generateFileName(filename) {                       
            var ext_regex = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;  
            var ext = ext_regex.exec(filename)[1]; 
            var date = new Date().getTime(); 
            var charbank = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            var fString = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                fString+= charbank[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
            }
            fString+=date + '.' + ext;

            return fString; 
        }

        var tempfile;
        var newfile; 
        var filename; 

        var newForm = new formidable.IncomingForm(); 
        newForm.keepExtensions = true;  
        newForm.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            tempfile = files.upload.path;           
            filename = generateFileName(files.upload.name);
            newfile = os.tmpDir() + '/' + filename; 
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plain'});
            res.end();          
        })   

        newForm.on('end', function() {
            fs.rename('tempfile', 'newfile' + function() {

                gm(newfile).resize(300).write(newfile, function() {                 
                    fs.readfile(newfile, function(err, buf) { 
                        var req = knoxClient.put(filename, {
                            'Content-Length': buf.length, 
                            'Content-Type': 'image/JPG'                         
                        })

                        req.on('response', function(res) {
                            if (res.statusCode == 200) {

                                var newImage = new singleImageModel({
                                    filename: filename,
                                    votes: 0    
                                }).save();

                                Socket.emit('status', {'message': 'saved!!', 'delay': 3000});
                                socket.emit('doUpdate', {});
                                fs.unlink(newfile, function() {

                                    console.log('local file deleted');
                                })
                            }
                        })

                        req.end(buf); 
                    })                              
                });

            })
        })      
    })

    app.use('/', router);   
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FromMyLens</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="../js/fml_utils.js"></script>
    <!-- add the socket.io script -->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


    <script>

    $(function() {
        var host = '{{host}}';

        $(document).on('click', '#submitPic', function() {
            uploadNow();        
        })
        var socket = io(host);
        socket.on('status', function(data) {
            showStatus(data.message, data.delay);
        })

        socket.on('doupdate', function() {
            renderlist();
        })

        function uploadNow() {
            $('.progress').fadeIn(100);
            var uploadURL = host + '/upload';
            var uploadFile = $('#uploadPic');

            if (uploadFile.val() != '') {
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append("upload", uploadFile.files[0]) 
                ajax({

                    method:'post',
                    url:uploadURL,
                    success:function() {
                        $('.progress').fadeOut(200);
                        uploadFile.val('');
                    },

                    progress: function(e) {
                        if(e.lengthComputable) {
                            var perc = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
                            $('.progress').css('width', (perc + '%'));
                        }
                    },

                    payload:form                    

                })              
            }   
        }       
    })  

    </script>   
</head>

<body>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class="topdeck">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>FromMyLens</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" name="uploadPic" id="uploadPic">
                <button id="submitPic"> submit</button>

                <div class="progressBarDiv">
                    <div class="progress"></div>
                </div>
                <h5 class="status"> status</h5>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="gallery">
            <ul>
                <!--repeat for all images --> 

                <li>
                    <div class ="overlay">
                        <div class="voteControl">
                            <a href="#" class"upvote">
                                <img src="../images/likeBtn.png" alt="click here to vote up!">
                                <h4>100</h4>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imageHolder">
                        <img src="../images/test.JPG " id="#sampleImage">

                    </div>
                </li>
                <!--repeat this -->

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will really appreciate any help in this matter (: